# ES6 exported default function not seen as typeof function with eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, eslint, es6-modules

I want to create a library file where I export a default function that accepts some props.

**namespace.js**

```
import strings from './utils/strings.js'

export default (name, { commands, desc, builder, ...opts }) => {
    if (!name || !String(name).length) {
        throw new Error('Namespaces must have a name!')
    }
    return Object.assign(
        {
            command: name,
            desc,
            builder: (y) => {
                if (builder) {
                    builder(y)
                } else if (
                    commands &&
                    Array.isArray(commands) &&
                    commands.length
                ) {
                    commands.forEach((c) => y.command(c))
                } else if (
                    commands &&
                    typeof commands === 'object' &&
                    Object.keys(commands).length
                ) {
                    Object.keys(commands).forEach((command) => {
                        y.command(Object.assign({ command }, commands[command]))
                    })
                } else {
                    throw new Error(
                        'Namespaces must have at least one command or provide a builder function'
                    )
                }

                y.demandCommand(1, strings.missingCommand)
                y.recommendCommands()
                y.check((argv) => {
                    if (y.getCommandInstance().getCommands().length === 0) {
                        // Only for namespaces, not commands themselves
                        return true
                    }
                    const command = argv._[y.getContext().commands.length]
                    if (
                        !command ||
                        y
                            .getCommandInstance()
                            .getCommands()
                            .indexOf(command) === -1
                    ) {
                        throw new Error(strings.unrecognizedCommand)
                    }
                    return true
                })
            },
        },
        opts
    )
}
```

**index.js**
The exported namespace.js file is imported and exported in index.js of the library.

```
import namespace from './lib/namespace.js'

export default {
    chalk,
    inquirer,
    namespace,
    xxxxx
}
```

How I used it in my project. The library is installed with yarn.

**usedfile.js**

```
import namespace from '@openhat/helpers'

export default namespace('scripts', {
    desc: 'Scripts for development',
    builder: (yargs) =>
        yargs
            .option('cwd', {
                description: 'working directory to use (defaults to cwd)',
            })
            .commandDir('commands'),
})
```

When I run an eslint test on the code, I got the error:

```
export default namespace('scripts', {
               ^

TypeError: namespace is not a function
```

Comment: Thats because the default object here is unnamed, so you need to `import { namespace } from "index.js";` or `import Lib from "index/.s";` and then `Lib.namespace(...)`

Comment: @somethinghere do you mean `import { namespace } from "./lib/namespace.js";`

Comment: @Andy thanks. But I have tried the `import {namespace} from './lib/namespace.js'` . I got the syntax error `SyntaxError: The requested module './lib/namespace.js' does not provide an export named 'namespace'`. Which is because I exported as default. That is why I did the `import namespace from './lib/namespace.js'`

Comment: Yes I mean `import { namespace }` - sorry, quick typing results in errors. But since you are exporting a default object, your only option is `import DefaultObject from "path";` and then using `DefaultObject.namespace` or destructuring the object itself ( `const { namespace } = DefaultObject` ). --- this is because exports are just objects, and default is just one of their keys. The subkeys in default itself won't destructure there, because they are not "module keys" but keys on the "module.default" object.

Comment: @somethinghere In index.js, I `import DefaultObject from './lib/namespace.js'`. I export as `export default { namespace: DefaultObject.namespace }. In usedfile.js I import as `import namespace from '@openhat/cli-helpers'`. And uses as `export default namespace('scripts', {...})`. But then got the `namespace is not a function` error. It seems eslint does not recognize the function as function. It was working with commonJS require.

Comment: It seems the problem is not that usedfile.js is not seeing the namespace but it is not recognizing it as a function.

Comment: I’m sorry, all I can conclude is that regardless of what you say, your import syntax is usedfile should not work like you have it now. Exporting a default object is not the same as exporting them individually, and I understand why eslint would error as in my understanding, its the correct conclusion: namespace itself is an object here, not a function. And that object contains another key of namespace.